# Get the data of every 30 mint Data From Sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a table [image]

I want to group by node wise so that i can get the Total Call land on a particular node,but i want the total call of every 30 Minute (Node wise and Access_DateWise) and the output should be  Something Like

[image]

Note :Node Name Is in another Master Table You can Show Only Node Id here
Hope I have made myself Clear .looking forward to see Your Answer.

Comment: You may need to use a calendar table here, to generate all the possible intervals (which granted themselves may be restricted by a `WHERE` clause).

Comment: Kindly Explain How @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you need help creating a job that sends a mail with this information every 30 minutes...or do you need an SQL-question that returns the result of the second picture..?

Comment: I want To Transfer This Interval Data To another Table  Which Is the Second Image In Question @Danieboy

Comment: @ashishjayara:please check here to improve your question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/